# Stream<Bucket> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my application, I get AWS Bucket list with my method **s3client.listBuckets()**. My aim is to convert AWS Bucket List into DTO list.

Here's the problem:

```
The method map(Function<? super Bucket,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Bucket> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> bucket) -> {})Java(67108979)
```

Normally this kind of a functionality would have no problem with Entity -> DTO conversion, what is the difference?

```
private List<BucketDTO> convertIntoDTO(List<Bucket> buckets){
    buckets.stream()
        .map(
            bucket -> {
               // ..
            }
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

protected List<BucketDTO> getList() {
    List<Bucket> buckets = s3client.listBuckets();
    return convertIntoDTO(buckets);
}
```

---

As a quick solution, I decided to go with a loop. But still not sure why stream().map()... didn't work.

```
protected List<BucketDTO> convertIntoDTO(List<Bucket> buckets) {
    List<BucketDTO> bucketDTOList = new ArrayList<BucketDTO>()

    for(Bucket bucket : buckets) {
        BucketDTO bucketDTO = new BucketDTO();
        bucketDTO.setName(bucket.getName());
        bucketDTO.setDate(bucket.getCreationDate());
        bucketDTOList.add(bucketDTO);
    }

    return bucketDTOList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re just missing the `collect()` to collect the stream into the resulting list. As well as a return statement in the `convertIntoDTO` method, which I’m assuming you just missed when listing the code here?

```
private List<BucketDTO> convertIntoDTO(List<Bucket> buckets){
   return buckets.stream()
    .map(
        bucket -> {
           // ..
        }
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what your lambda is returning, so no one can help you with that. It could be your lambda is OK and you're just missing the `return` keyword before `buckets.stream()`.

However, if you implement the following method:

```
private BucketDTO convert(Bucket bucket) {
    return // your code here
}
```

This will work:

```
private List<BucketDTO> convertIntoDTO(List<Bucket> buckets){
    return buckets.stream()
      .map(this::convert)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And will be easier to read and test.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to kick yourself.

The signature of map is:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

The important part is that the argument is of type `Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper` where `? super T` is the element of the mapped stream (in your case `Bucket`) and `? extends R` is the **return type** (in your case `BucketDTO`).

In order for the compiler to work out the return type the anonymous function has to actually return a typed Object. In your case this is the fix:

```
buckets.stream()
    .map(
         bucket -> {
             return new BucketDTO(); // NB: so the compiler can work out the return class of the anonymous method
         }
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```